# How do I encode an HTML element attribute

Tags: node.js, ejs

How do I encode an HTML attribute from an EJS template in NodeJS. I need to do something like:

```
<img onmouseover=<% myString %> />
```

Where myString would then be properly escape and quoted to be a valid attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
npm install node-html-encoder

app.locals.encoder = require('node-html-encoder').Encoder;

<%= encoder.htmlEncode('<foo /> "bar"') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
myString = myString.replace(/'|\\/g, '\\$&');
```

But if you need to escape HTML special characters too you can try:

```
myString = myString.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
myString = myString.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
myString = myString.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

P.S. take care to not escape JavaScript operators using the replacements for HTML characters!

Comment: -1 : Don't do things like this manually, because it's never as simple as it seems.

Comment: If you are going to encode attributes yourself, make sure you [escape all the characters specified by OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes)